# iPhone and UIWebView: Force HTTPS (rewrite URLs on the fly)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, https

I have a web based application that uses Cocoa/CocoaTouch's UIWebView. I want (need?) to force all HTTP connections to HTTPS. Note that I am interested in forcing the initial, landing URL to HTTPS and all the intermediate fetches to HTTPS also. Motivation: [New Tricks for Defeating SSL in Practice](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-dc-09/Marlinspike/BlackHat-DC-09-Marlinspike-Defeating-SSL.pdf) and [sslstrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/).

Is it possible to configure WebView to only use HTTPS? The [UIWebView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does not even mention HTTPS. Considering Apple does not allow me to [disable JavaScript in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302975/uiwebview-can-you-disable-javascript), I doubt I can make the configuration change on the view.

Or does the answer lie somewhere in `NSURLRequest`, `NSURLConnection`, and possibly delegate methods? I read [URL Loading System Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-BAJEAIEE), and I don't see where I am able to change requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the request you can proxy UIWebView so all requests are intercepted and then replace http with https, and make the request from the proxy. One way of doing this would be to subclass NSURLCache and override the method cachedResponseForRequest.

Comment: Hi xrcsblue. Forgive my ignorance here. Wouldn't a proxy require another application (to receive requests from my client)?

Comment: I don't mean an external proxy. When the browser makes a request the method(in the subclasss in your app code) will be invoked and the request url+data will be passed in. You can then pass the same request to another url of your choice (change http to https in your case)